# Суммирование строчек

Tags: jquery, javascript

Демо:
https://jsfiddle.net/Room13/fk3ykcw4/1/

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии Enter по полю "количество" это количество умножалось на цену и отображалось в "итого". А внизу таблицы автиматически выводилась общая сумма. Или хотя бы пните, в какую сторону смотреть...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто - в атрибуте "data-*" можно хранить цену. Так же и скидку.
После отлова нажатия `Enter` - `keyup`, `keyCode = 13` - можно брать брать все параметры, считать как-то так: `(price * count) - (price * count * disc)`. Скидка должна быть в формате: `15% = 0.15; 5% = 0.05`.
Выводить посчитанное в "Итого" и запускать функцию перерасчёта общей суммы - она пробегается по всем ячейкам "Итого", суммирует их и выводит окончательный вердикт.

Comment: Логика то понятна... а вот "выводить" и "взять параметры" с этим у меня немного сложно :)

Comment: @Jekson353, ну... Могу состряпать пример...

Comment:     var x="1";
    var value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputA-"+x).value);
это например понятно... вывод цифр нужно не в input а в div (затирая старые цифры)

Comment: @Jekson353, фиддл завис - на сохранение 500 кидает.  
Как поднимется - скину ссыль на пример.

Comment: жду с нетерпением

Comment: Короче, фиддл поднимется нескоро, тогда вот: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNzJRe

Comment: @Jekson353, фиддл поднялся, вот: https://jsfiddle.net/v81x58c5/

Comment: Спасибо большое! А не поможете завернуть все это в  $("body").on?? Т.к. скрипт присваивает обработчик после загрузки DOM, а у меня есть данные, которые динамически подгружаются на страницу, и они этим скриптом уже не обрабатываются. =(